# How would I drop something directly in the middle of a vertical pipe?

Tags: experimental-physics

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but it is for a physics experiment.

I'm trying to find out how the internal diameter of a copper pipe affects the time it takes for a magnet to drop through. Dropping the magnet in the centre would allow me to ensure consistency for each drop.

Comment: How tight of a fit is it?

Comment: Use a precise funnel

Comment: Drop the magnet down a plastic tube held in the centre of the copper pipe.

Comment: I had a university research job where we did these drop-tower like experiments that required 2mm ball bearings to collide in mid air and intersect at a repeatable height and with repeatable horizontal offset (controlling contact angle)...  We held them from above with a vacuum suction (stiff metal hole), and used a solenoid valve to shut off the vacuum. Got good timing control and very clean release that way.

Comment: @EricS I'm using a square magnet, cus I couldn't find a round one. Its dimensions are 1.2cm x 1cm x 1cm. The diameters I'm using are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 cm

Comment: @Transistor I'm trying not to let the magnet touch any surface, cus that would result in friction

Comment: @PeteW Won't the speed of the ball bearing be changed then?

Comment: Here's another way. Take a piece of clear plastic sheet material, put the magnet being dropped on the bottom, and another magnet on top, so they attract each other (i.e. pinching the plastic). Select the plastic thickness so the force is mild-moderate, just enough to hold the weight of the bottom magnet. When assembled, position it all on your copper tube and hold it down with something. Now lift the top magnet straight up. The bottom magnet should fall.

Comment: Excerpted from memolition.com. "Magnets are not attracted to copper, but incredibly strong magnets interact with copper in a pretty amazing way. If you drop a neodymium magnet down through a copper pipe it’s descent is slowed. The stronger the magnet and the thicker the pipe, the slower the fall. Take a look. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keMpUaoA3Tg This is an excellent demonstration of **Lenz’s law and eddy currents**. If you’re not familiar with Lenz’s Law, Wikipedia defines it as: “An induced electromotive force (emf) always gives rise to a current whose magnetic field opposes the origin

Comment: To avoid air resistance & piston effects within the tube, as the magnet falls through, the entire apparatus might need to be in a vacuum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Illustration following up from the comments

We used vacuum to hold the ball bearing being dropped, from above. The ball was hand placed up against the output port of a manifold. Around it was open air. The port holding the ball connected to COMMON port of a 3/2 solenoid valve. NC to vacuum regulator,  NO vent to atmosphere. When valve vented the output, part went into free fall.

There wasn't much to it, really, although we had the benefit of symmetry, and the sphere-circle contact made great repeatability in horizontal position.

[image: fine-art]

Comment: Align with a laser pistol site. Match parallax to target.